# Square of a Quadrilateral through coordinates formula as an expression of matrix determinant

Tags: geometry

For a quadrilateral:

[image]

For a triangle:

[image]

Is it possible to express the formula for a quadrilateral in a simpler form (easier to remember), for example through a matrix detrerminant, like it is with triangle?

Comment: Your title shouldn't be "Square of..." but "Area of ..."

Answer (score 0):

It is given by [Shoelace Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) in the following form (n=4):

[image]

for a triangle write a determinant as (adding 1s, because determinant is defined only for a square matrix)

[image]

And it is valid for any polygon (convex and concave but not self-intersecting)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This image might help you to remember the shoelace formula. Note that in the case of a quadrilateral you just have to add another line with $x_4$ and $y_4$.